# Upload file button for remote files

Tags: html, unix

Here's the scenario.  I have a simple browse button.  Right now, it opens up the folder hierarchy on my local computer. (PC).

However, I want to pick a file from a remote unix server which I have access to. Is there a way to display the file hierarchy of the remote unix server WITHOUT having to mount the drive?

Are there other options other than using a java applet?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Does the Unix machine have the remote server mounted; for example, is it using NFS?  Define "have access to."

Comment: Not currently; but I have root access to all machines.

What I want is a typical "browse file" button, that instead of pulling up my windows desktop, pulls up a path to the unix server.

Comment: So you want the browse button to bring up a dialog containing a hierarchy of files that exist on the web server? If so, what server-side language is the web server running? (I apologise if I've completely missed the point - not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly)

Comment: Close. I want the browse button to bring up a dialog containing a hierarchy of files of a computer that I can access through ssh from my webserver.  

So the webserver (that is displaying the browse button) will be able to display files from a networked unix computer.

Comment: Ok cool, are you using PHP? (and if so, what version?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why; I've had much difficulty with installing anything on the solaris machine.  So i've decided to go a slightly different route -- I found out that the machine is already mounted properly, so I can simply switch user accounts to access what I need -- without SSH.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really want an applet you can do it server-side in PHP by using this something like this to let the user select a folder:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('host', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'ls -a --file-type');
?>
```

Just parse the `$stream` variable to identify the folders (the ones ending with /) and present them in a table.

I guess this solves your problem. If you want the user to upload a file just put a simple file upload field, Once the user have selected a folder and uploaded a file in a temporal location in the server just move it with SSH too:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('host', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/temporal/filename', '/remote/filename');
?>
```

For getting this working you need to have [enabled SSH2 libraries for PHP in your server](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/).

Comment: Sigh, running into issues installing on Solaris

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how it is in Unix, but in Windows, you can either map a drive letter to remote path, or simply type the remote path in the browse dialog (`\\server\share\filename`)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the regular input type file, invoke a Java applet. You can use VFS from apache to access your UNIX machines. VFS API supports many file access protocols.
http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine recommended Samba:
http://us3.samba.org/samba/

It apparently lets you link a unix server as a windows file/print server, which should show up in a file browser. :)